# How to delete multiple empty spaces simultaneously?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a passage here but it separate via new line such as this picture. **How to delete the space separate between the words simultaneously** because there are so many in my original documents (the picture is just example). The final result should be a **one sentence only**.

**Edited:**
I do change the new picture to give a better prespective
[image]

Comment: Vertical spaces or horizontal? Can you display the hidden non-printing formatting marks? http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm Please edit your post to show a screenshot with them.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Horizontal space

Comment: @CharlesKenyon The red line just for references because I cannot show the "space"

Comment: Go to the linked reference and it explains how to show non-printing formatting marks, which for our purposes, includes spaces. Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

### Replace two spaces with one and redo it until done.

For horizontal spaces, in the Replace dialog (Ctrl+H) put two spaces in the find box and one space in the replace with box. Hit Replace All repeatedly until Word tells you it can't find any.